# SElinux error :ValueError: Port tcp/5000 already defined

Tags: port, httpd, selinux

I have been trying to add an exception to SELinux for apache on port 5000.So I used the command:

```
 # semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
```

But returns the error,

```
ValueError: Port tcp/5000 already defined
```

I tried to check if this is so with the command:

```
semanage port -l |grep 5000
```

which gave the output,

```
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

As you can see, 5000 is not on the list.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?
Thank you in advance for your effort

So I found that another service had a defined status for TCP port 5000.

But by replacing the `-a` option with `-m` for modify, added tcp port 5000 to `http_port_t`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

So I found that another service had a defined status for TCP port 5000.

But by replacing the `-a` option with `-m` for modify, added `tcp port 5000` to `http_port_t`

So the command that worked was:

```
# semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
```

Answer (score 11):

On the systems I have to hand (C6, C7 and F24), tcp port 5000 has an SELinux context of `commplex_port_t`. This will be why, when you try to add it you get the error message

```
/usr/sbin/semanage: Port tcp/5000 already defined
```

To change the context of tcp port 5000 from `commplex_port_t` to `http_port_t` you will need to use the -m | --modify switch

```
-m, --modify     Modify a OBJECT record NAME
```

so

```
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
```

should do what you want

```
semanage port -l | grep 5000
http_port_t                tcp      5000, 80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it did what i needed. I stumbled on the answer on the comment section of a blog with the help of my colleague as well :)